# Data_max is not respect in mybatis

Tags: java, sql, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I ned to get all element between a min date and max date so I do this

`data_min` and `data_max` are two string at the start so I do :

```
Criteria criteria = ....createCriteria();

            SimpleDateFormat formatter_date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd");

            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(data_min)) {

                criteria.andDataGreaterThanOrEqualTo(formatter_date.parse(data_min));
            }
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(data_max)) {

                criteria.andDataLessThanOrEqualTo(formatter_date.parse(data_max));
            }
```

The problem is that if I put like min data value `27/12/2018` and max data value `28/12/2018`. It return me only elements that have date  `27/12/2018` but It doesn't return me the elements with date 28/12/2018. Anyone can help me?

Comment: May it be the problem that you store the date as timestamp in the database and it has time part (like hours, seconds etc)? In the criteria you parse only date so time part is `00:00:00.0000`. If the value in the db has any non zero component in time it will not be returned.

Comment: @RomanKonoval date in db is 2011-03-11 it doesn't have hours or minutes or seconds.

Comment: Share the query and the mapping configuration, please. What database are you using and what is the type of the column that contains the date?

Comment: One more common problem is the difference in timezones. It may be that the timestamp that you pass as a parameter is converted at some stage and it may become not what you expect when the comparison in the DB happens

Comment: I resolve to add at the new Date(data_max.getTime() +84600000);